# Python, ACR122U NFC reader can it read the ID of the Android phone is that possible?

Tags: python, nfc, nfc-p2p

I have a ACS ACR122U NFC Reader / Writer when i hover over the reader with my Samsung s7. The led becomes green so the reader understands the mobile.

The idea is when a employee comes to work he hover over the reader he gets clocked in.

On github i found some solutions for reading the nfc with python:

https://github.com/StevenTso/ACS-ACR122U-NFC-Reader
https://github.com/SaundersB/NFC_Reader

Maybe i don't understand it right but shouldn't i get a ID of the phone or able to write data to it or is it just a reader (but why does file transfer works over nfc)?

Maybe i just need to buy a nfc-tag and use that for the clocking?

Answer (score 1):

You could emulate a card on Phone, but you need to install an app on each phone to put it in [HCE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html) Host Card Emulation mode. After you NFC reader could communicate with phone.

Easiest solution is to buy tags with unique ID.

Comment: @Janis , Is it useful ?